# Does LinkedHashMap#put keep order when key is override? (JAVA)

Tags: java

Here would be a LinkedHashMap, imagine it had many values inside of it.

LinkedHashMap map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

My question is, if one of the existing values was, for example, at index 4 and the same key was .put into the map, will it simply replace the value and remain at 4? Or, will it add onto the end?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation of `LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) explicitly points this out:

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key is *re-inserted* into the map. (A key `k` is reinserted into a map `m` if `m.put(k, v)` is invoked when `m.containsKey(k)` would return `true` immediately prior to the invocation.)

So the value is replaced, but the iteration order will remain the same. For your example, the entry with key 4 will remain at the same position for the iteration.